# Trying to compare clipboard value to a variable value to remove certain text and copy the remainder to a teraterm window

Tags: autohotkey

Notice the if statements below. I am copying the terminal output to the clipboard.  It contains `RP/0/RSP0/CPU0:cobn9-hub#`. I want to remove `RP/0/RSP0/CPU0:` from from the clipboard and it does work however when I try to add an additional string to that variable `var1` nothing works.

```
var1  := "RP/0/RSP0/CPU0:,mnet-prd-hub"
```

without `,mnet-prd-hub` it will remove the unwanted text but if I add something else to `var1` it stops working.

I want to also remove `mnet-prd-hub:`
from `mnet-prd-hub:/home/data/configs/current$/home/data/configs/current$`

I've tried if var contains `%clipboard"`
I've tried clipboard contains `%var1%`
I've tried `IfInstring` with no luck.
So I am asking for someones tutelage.

I've tried for hours with no luck any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2   
#IfWinActive,  ahk_class VTWin32
::ttwa::
    var1 = 
    var1 :=
    clipboard = ; empty clipboard
    sleep 200
    send !e {enter}
    send s
    send {enter 100}
    sleep 100
    Send {click} 
    sleep 100
    send {click} 
    sleep 100
    send {click} 
    sleep 10
    MsgBox 1st %clipboard%   %var1%
    ;var1 represents a Cisco 9k this script removes var1 puts the proper name in the Title Window
    var1  := "RP/0/RSP0/CPU0:,mnet-prd-hub"
    MsgBox 2nd %clipboard%   %var1%
    ;if  var1 in %clipboard%
    IfInString, var1, %clipboard%
    {
        MsgBox 3rd  %var1%      %clipboard%
        StringReplace, clipboard, clipboard, %var1%,, All
        StringReplace, clipboard, clipboard, #,, all
        MsgBox 4rd  %var1%      %clipboard%
        var1 = 
        var1 :=
        MsgBox 5th   %var1%      %clipboard%
    }
    else 
    {
        MsgBox 6th  %var1%      %clipboard%
        StringReplace, clipboard, clipboard, #, , all
        MsgBox 6th  %var1%      %clipboard%
    }
    sleep 200
    send !s
    sleep 200
    Send w
    send %clipboard% {enter}
    sleep 200
    send !e s {enter}
#IfWinActive
return
```

Comment: Maybe the commas in strings are interpreted as parameter separators because you use the old syntax. Try using [if expression](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/IfExpression.htm) syntax: `if instr(var1, clipboard)` (outer parentheses here aren't needed as the function is the first expression)

Comment: I use this script with teraterm to rename the window title and tab.  That way I know what router I am in.

Comment: Thank you for your response. In testing the script it was unable to find the text in var1 that was in the clipboard.

I use this script with teraterm to rename the window title and tab so I know which device I am logged into.

For some reason the IfInString cannot see either element in var1 it skips the first part of the if completely.

Comment: Does anyone know how to get an account on www.autohotkey.com there seems to be a ton of information I can't get to.

Comment: ::ttwa::
    uNames := "mnet-prd-hub:,RP/0/RSP0/CPU0:,RP/0/RSP1/CPU0:"
    
    Loop, Parse, uNames, `,
        clipboard := RegexReplace(clipboard, a_loopfield)

    ; msgbox % clipboard
    
    if (WinActive("ahk_class VTWin32"))
    {
        sleep 200
        send !s
        sleep 200
        Send w
        send %clipboard% {enter}
        sleep 200
        send !e s {enter}
        
    } else if (WinActive("ahk_class PuTTY"))
    {
        ; steps for putty
    }

Comment: Raptor helped me out on this it works now thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are looking for, but since you said you had problems adding a string to your variable, try this code, it will show you how to remove and add text to/from your variables:

```
var1  := "RP/0/RSP0/CPU0:,mnet-prd-hub" 
MsgBox, %var1% `n`nClick OK to remove RP/0/RSP0/CPU0: from that string!
var1 := RemoveFromString(var1, "RP/0/RSP0/CPU0:")
MsgBox, %var1% `n`nClick OK to add mnet-prd-hub:/home/data/configs/current$/home/data/configs/current$ to that string!
var1 := AddToString(var1, "mnet-prd-hub:/home/data/configs/current$/home/data/configs/current$")
MsgBox, %var1% `n`nClick OK to remove mnet-prd-hub: from that string!
var1 := RemoveFromString(var1, "mnet-prd-hub:")
MsgBox, %var1%

RemoveFromString(string,stringToRemove) {
    Return StrReplace(string, stringToRemove, "")
}
AddToString(string,stringToAdd) {
    Return string stringToAdd
}
```

**Edit:**
So you want to see if the contents of var1 are to be found in the clipboard?
It can be done like this:

```
If InStr(Clipboard,var1) {
    MsgBox, the contents of var1 were found in the clipboard.
}
```

**Edit 2:**
Like this?

```
If InStr(Clipboard,var1) {
    Clipboard := RemoveFromString(Clipboard,var1)
}
RemoveFromString(string,stringToRemove) {
    Return StrReplace(string, stringToRemove, "")
}
```

Comment: If I am in a terminal session 3 clicks will copy the device I am in to the clipboard. Then I want to see if var1 values are in the clipboard.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I used the MsgBox to reveal the content of the variables.  Is there an easier way to to this.

When I triple click a line it is copied into the clipboard.  The content in the clipboard can contain the text in var1.  If it does I want any content from var1 removed from the copied text in the clipboard.

Comment: For example a routers name is RP/0/RSP0/CPU0:cobn9-hub.  I want to remove the content that is in var1 so the clipboard only contains cobn9-hub.

var1 contains  var1 := "RP/0/RSP0/CPU0:", "mnet-prd-hub"  so if RP/0/RSP0/CPU0: is in the clipboard I want to remove it.  

Or it mnet-prd-hub is in the clipboard or whatever text I add to var1 I would like it removed from the clipboard.

Sorry if I wasn't clear I am doing my best.  Thanks.

Comment: I am sorry I meant to remove and part of var1 from texted copied to the clipboard.

Comment: RP/0/RSP0/CPU0: is copied alone with cobn9-hub when the triple click happens  so it looks like this in the clipboard RP/0/RSP0/CPU0:cobn9-hub    the var1 contains RP/0/RSP0/CPU0: that is the part I need removed from the clipboard so it only says cobn9-hub.

Comment: I am going to try out what you suggested to see if I can get it to work. But if you have any comments please do not hesitate.

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly a genius helped me out on this.

```
Groupadd, TerminalWindows, ahk_class VTWin32
Groupadd, TerminalWindows, ahk_class PuTTY



SetTitleMatchMode, 2   
#If WinActive("ahk_group TerminalWindows")
::ttwa::
    uNames := "mnet-prd-hub:,RP/0/RSP0/CPU0:,RP/0/RSP1/CPU0:"
    Clipboard= ; empty clipboard
    sleep 200
    send !e {enter}
    send s
    send {enter 100}
    sleep 100
    Send {click} 
    sleep 100
    send {click} 
    sleep 100
    send {click} 
    sleep 10

    Loop, Parse, uNames, `,
        clipboard := RegexReplace(clipboard, a_loopfield)

    ; msgbox % clipboard

    if (WinActive("ahk_class VTWin32"))
    {
        sleep 200
        send !s
        sleep 200
        Send w
        send %clipboard% {enter}
        sleep 200
        send !e s {enter}

    } else if (WinActive("ahk_class PuTTY"))
    {
        ; steps for putty
    }
#IfWinActive
return
```

Comment: Thank you to everyone who helped me I really appreciate it.  Check out the coding in autohotkey tool kit.  I am assuming you all understand it I do not.  My journey has just begun.    https://github.com/RaptorX/AHK-ToolKit